# How to use a JSON response data set from a feature to build multiple new endpoints

Tags: karate

I have a json file with different sets of data (array of more than 5 rows). I would like to use it as path and query parameters to build new endpoints and validate the response of newly built endpoints to find a specific value. I would like to run it as loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Peter. I am trying to test whether an event is published into kafka topic. It is 2 step validation
Step 1: Find out the start & end offset and partitions present in a topic ( a JSON response)
Step 2: Use the data from JSON response from Step 1 to dig through each partition to find the right event.

Checking if Karate can support this.

Answer (score 1):

And I would like you to actually take some time to read the documentation and then ask specific questions. Please refer this:

https://github.com/intuit/karate#dynamic-scenario-outline

```
Feature: scenario outline using a dynamic table

Background:
    * def kittens = read('../callarray/kittens.json')

Scenario Outline: cat name: <name>
    Given url demoBaseUrl
    And path 'cats'
    And request { name: '<name>' }
    When method post
    Then status 200
    And match response == { id: '#number', name: '<name>' }

    # the single cell can be any valid karate expression
    # and even reference a variable defined in the Background
    Examples:
    | kittens |
```